# jsTree open node on rollover

Tags: jstree

Any guidance on how to use jsTree as a menu?  Specifically, I'm looking to have a given node open when the user rolls over a node in the tree (as opposed to clicking on the node to open).

I've searched the documentation and note that there is an event handler for double click, but there are no callbacks for mouse roll over events.

Also, related to above, is there a way to have the tree be presented horizontally as opposed to vertically (which is the default layout)?

I'm new to jsTree so please forgive me if this too basic of a question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, try to attach to the **hover_node.jstree** event e.g.

```
$("jstree_id").bind("hover_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
     var node = data.rslt.obj, // the hovered node 
         tree_instance = data.inst; // tree instance

     tree_instance.open_node(node);
});
```

Hope this helps a bit.